# Expose TCP and UDP on a k8s cluster with one LoadBalancer

Tags: kubernetes, tcp, udp, traefik

I've got a single-node k8s cluster running on a VPS with Traefik configured as it's Ingress controller and MetalLB as the LoadBalancer.
This is working great for all my TCP servers, however, I would like to host a dedicated game server in the cluster, which needs to be exposed over UDP.
Now, I know Traefik supports UDP as well as TCP, but the problem is getting it to Traefik.
I cannot expose multiple protocols over one Service of type LoadBalancer, meaning that that option will not work.
I could try exposing the service through NodePorts, but that will change the mapping of the ports which I want to prevent. Also, using `port-forward` is not possible, as this [does not support UDP](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47862).

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that MetalLB supports [IP sharing under some conditions!](https://metallb.universe.tf/usage/#ip-address-sharing).
I'll try this out.